# Portable rechargeable battery (power supply) for tablets and phones that will also jumpstart large vehicle engines

Tags: smartphones, tablet, power-supply, power, portable

I am seeking recommendations for a portable rechargeable battery pack.

***Requirements***

1. Reliable
2. Can *safely* power tablets and phones (only need 2.1A at once)
3. Can *reliably* jumpstart a large vehicle engine (4.0L)

***Preferences***

1. As low of a price as possible
2. As small as possible

***Bonus***

1. Has a carrying case (but not willing to pay extra for one)

Note: Costco currently sells such a device for $59.99, but I have been unable to find any reviews of it, nor do I know anyone who has tried one.